# Give and Go on NBA 2k11 Wii

Tags: nintendo-wii, nba2k11

I'm playing NBA 2k11 on a Wii, using a Classic Controller. On the Scrimmage help, it says that to perform a Give and Go, I need to hold `L` and `R`, and then pass using `b`. However, whenever I try that, it results in an Alley Oop pass (which is usually done by holding `L` and pressing `b`). Is there any setting I need to tweak?

Comment: Have you tried L and R, and then hitting "a"?  I seem to recall in previous iterations of the game that was how you performed a give and go.

Comment: I did, and it doesn't seem to work either: it tries to make an alley oop as well.